# has_many through association wice_grid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I am trying to get the role of user in a grid table using wice_grid gem

```
user has_many :roles, :through => :assignments

role has_many :users, :through => :assignments
```

in users_controller.rb

```
@users_grid = initialize_grid(User,
                                  :include => [:assignments, :roles])
```

what should i write in the view in order to make the role of a user appears , and i cant get it from the documentation so help needed please how to wrote it in the view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a try with followings. lets name is a column in users table and role_name is a column in roles table.

```
<%= grid(@users_grid) do |g|
  # Here I have defined the column name. Column names are defined with parameter ':name' and the ':attribute' defines which column to map in the users table for this column.
  g.column :name => 'User Name', :attribute => 'name' do |user|  # primary table
    link_to(user.name, user_path(user))
  end

  # Regarding join tables or associations, we need to specify the model name as here, I have defined model: 'Role'.
  g.column name: 'Having Roles', attribute: 'role_name', model: 'Role' do |user|
    # here we are using the associations showing the data for the joints table.
    user.roles.collect{|role| role.role_name}.to_sentence
  end

  g.column do |user|
    link_to('Edit', edit_user_path(user))
  end
end%>
```

You can check the code of a sample example https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid_testbed

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein, I have added comments to my answer for the explanation.

Comment: could you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495228/private-pub-issue-in-rails-application, i cant find a way to solve this

Comment: and i need a way in wice_grid to put 2 values in one cell , like view/edit for profile of a user